# How to get the index of the object being rendered in HTML using Django

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, django

I'm displaying a mysql database using Django on a webpage. I'm rendering the database as `obj` from `views.py` and using it in `index.html`. I want to know is it possible to get the index of this object `obj`? i.e., In the same loop iteration I want the next row's value, for example in row 10th's iteration, with `{{ b.col2 }}` I get col2's value for the 10th row, how can get I 11th row's `b.col2` value in the same loop iteration and store it in a temporary variable for comparison. Is there a way I could get index of the object?

```
  <script> 
            var i = 1; </script>
            {% for b in obj %} 

        <tr>
            <td>{{ b.col1 }}</td>
            <td><span class="wrapped"><span>{{ b.col2 }}</span></span> </td>
            <td id='myTable'></td>          
            <td id='myTable'></td>
            <td>{{ b.col5 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col6 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col7 }}</td>
        </tr>



{% endfor %}
</table>
```

UPDATE:

views.py:

```
def display(request):

    return render_to_response('index.html', {'obj': my_model.objects.order_by('col2')})
```

Comment: Can you share your views.py?

Comment: @mattjegan Shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `forloopcounter` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/)) to help you know the index you're on, along with `obj.index` to help you get the value of next index. This is not recommended though, Django Template is specifically designed to handle simplicity, while you're recommended to do the rest in python.

Also read about slice, which can be used for lists ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)).

Edit for Full Answer:

1. In your app directory create a folder called `templatetags`
2. inside `templatetags`, create a file called `__init__.py`
3. inside `templatetags`, create another file called `custom_tags.py`
4. open `custom_tags.py` and add the following code:

> ---

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def next_object(value, arg):
    try:
        return value[int(arg)+1].col2
    except:
        return None
```

6. In your template add the following code:

> ---

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{% for b in obj %}
    {% ifequal forloop.counter0 10 %} <!–– We are at index 10 -->
        {% with obj|next_object:forloop.counter0 as next_object %}
            {{ next_object }} <!–– Returns value of col2 from index 11 -->
        {% endwith %}
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Okay with {{ forloop.counter }}, I get the index of each row but how do I get next row's cell value in the iteration? Something like var temp = {{ (b+1).col2 }} ???

Answer (score 0):

When you use a templated for-loop in Django, a few variables get set automatically for you. One such variable is `forloop.counter` which will be 1-indexed over your loop. That is, it's first value will be 1 and then on each iteration of the loop, it will increase by 1. You would use it like so:

```
{% for b in obj %} 
    {{ forloop.counter }} <!-- your logic here -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Okay with {{ forloop.counter }}, I get the index of each row but how do I get next row's cell value in the iteration? Something like var temp = {{ (b+1).col2 }} ???